# Load jar with root loader

Tags: java, binding, groovy, classloader

I develop a library and one of its methods has the following form:

```
void setVars(def script) { 
  // script parameter is an instance of groovy.lang.Script loaded by Rootoader
  // MyBinding is part of the lib and extends groovy.lang.Binding 
  script.setBinding(new MyBinding()) 
}
```

Now, if the library is used as a jar file I get undefined method exception, as the script object is passed from the main application and is loaded by a RootLoader while MyBinding is loaded by `sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader`, which is its child. Is there any way to load the whole jar using RootClass Loader? For some reason, `rootLoader.loadClass("MyBinding")` returns a class loaded by AppClassLoader and does not reload it.

UPDATE with an example:

S.script (created by a user):

```
println 1
```

Main.groovy (created by the user):

```
class Main {
  static void main(String[] args) {
    Lib.setVars(S)
  }  
}
```

My lib.jar added by the user to a classpath:

```
class MyBinding extends Binding {
   //...
}

class Lib {
  static void setVars(Class scriptClass) { 
    def script = scriptClass.newInstance()
    //Exception as MyBinding is loaded by MyBinding 
    //while script class is loaded by RootLoaded
    script.setBinding(new MyBinding()) 
  }
}
```

Main.groovy is the file that is ran. I do it from eclipse where lib.jar is added to a project's classpath in a Java Build Path -> Libraries section (I expect users to use the library in this way or via maven).

Answer (score 1):

depends on how do you run the script?
couple of ways,

1. > java -cp lib/yourLib.jar;lib/groovy.jar
   >   org.codehaus.groovy.tools.GroovyStarter --classpath
   >   lib/yourBindingLib.jar;lib/.jar --main groovy.ui.GroovyMain
   >   YourScript.groovy
2. You can also specify the URL of your lib before putting it to use in the code,

   def bindingLib = new File("...");
   loader.addURL(bindingLib.toURI().toURL())

Comment: i do not have control over the main application from which a jar is used, can I reload the jar (or at least a set of classes) post factum?